# glfw how to destroy window in mainloop

Tags: c++, window, glfw

I am trying to develop a program using glfw where the window closes in the main loop. However, I get this weird run time error:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadDrawable
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (X_GLXSwapBuffers)
  Serial number of failed request:  158
  Current serial number in output stream:  158
```

Here is the code I'm trying to run

```
#include <GL/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if(!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(400, 400, "window", nullptr, nullptr);

    if(!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to destruct the window from inside the main loop?

Comment: Why do you call `glfwDestroyWindow` when the test `glfwWindowShouldClose` right before tells you not to close it?

Comment: @Ripi2 good point, does that mean I will have to manually use a ```while(true)``` loop and break if the window is closed? If so how do I create an event listener to alert me when the window is closed?

Comment: Just move `glfwDestroyWindow` right before `glfwTerminate`

Comment: Why do you want to destroy the window in the main loop? Why do you want to destroy the window immediately after the window was created?

Comment: @Rabbid76 the main goal was to make a window class and have a close method which could destroy the window from inside the mainloop if certain requirements are met (if statements)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I simplified the code for the purpose of the question, my question was wether I could call ```glfwDestroyWindow``` inside the main loop.

Comment: @MaximV Why would you call `glfwDestroyWindow` in the main loop. I don't understand what you want to achieve. That makes no sense at all. Why do you not just break the loop? After calling `glfwDestroyWindow` you can't call `glfwSwapBuffers` or `glfwPollEvents`. Thus the answer is no. You cannot call `glfwDestroyWindow` and after that `glfwSwapBuffers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call `glfwDestroyWindow` in the main loop. Here's how I did it.

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    
    if(!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(400, 400, "My Window", NULL, NULL);

    if(!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Q) == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
            break;
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Press the Q key to destroy the window. Try running this code to see if it will work. I ran this code and the process simply returned 0 without printing any error messages. I don't see why it shouldn't work for you.

Comment: So I just need to make sure I don't reiterate while the window is destroyed?

Comment: Yes. That is the purpose of the ```break``` statement.

Answer (score 1):

To utilize `glfwWindowShouldClose` more directly, use this...

```
glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
```

Though I think you still need to terminate the window regardless.
You can append this to the quit key.

```
...
main_loop();
...
glfwDestoryWindow(window);
```

To add it to the main loop is simple enough.

```
while (...)
{
  ...
  if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Q) == GLFW_PRESS)
  {
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    break;
  }
}
```

You can make it a callback too.

```
void keyboard_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
  if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
  {
    switch (key)
    {
      case GLFW_KEY_Q:
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }
  }
}
```